# Does Bing spell check API have an additional length restriction for mode = spell?

Tags: bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

The [Bing spell check API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt711411.aspx) has a 10,000 char limit for the chunk of text that the request would like to do a spell check [mode=spell] or proof read [mode=proof(default)].

However I am running into an issue where a chunk of misspelt text clearly under the limit of 10k, does not return back with flagged tokens in a spell check request, but does return back in the proof read request.

What gives? Is there a lower limit for Spell check?

Output for both requests below. I am using POST in both cases and both responses return a 200 OK

**Mode: spell**

*Request:*

> POST
>   https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/spellcheck/?mode=spell
>   HTTP/1.1 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Host:
>   api.cognitive.microsoft.com Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:
>   ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••
>
> Text=This is a long sentance with some mistakes in here. its supposed
>   to be a question but i can’t think of a long question. maybe that
>   means i don’t have something selious to ask?

*Response:*

> Vary: Accept-Encoding BingAPIs-TraceId:
>   2802E335D1A04D22865FCA6039E61233 X-MSEdge-ClientID:
>   3F1CA016365F6B862DF6AA10376E6A50 X-MSAPI-UserState: 97c3
>   BingAPIs-Market: en-US X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A:
>   2802E335D1A04D22865FCA6039E61233 Ref B:
>   E62A760E2E5891B3D022742C51159258 Ref C: Tue Jan 10 13:44:58 2017 PST
>   apim-request-id: 7b94e044-d1fe-4bbc-a153-4d4e5ef30586
>   Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;
>   preload Cache-Control: max-age=0, private Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2017
>   21:44:57 GMT P3P: CP="NON UNI COM NAV STA LOC CURa DEVa PSAa PSDa OUR
>   IND" Content-Length: 44 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   Expires: Tue, 10 Jan 2017 21:43:57 GMT
>
> {   "_type": "SpellCheck",   "flaggedTokens": [] }

**Mode: proof**

*Request:*

> POST
>   https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/spellcheck/?mode=proof
>   HTTP/1.1 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Host:
>   api.cognitive.microsoft.com Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:
>   ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••
>
> Text=This is a long sentance with some mistakes in here. its supposed
>   to be a question but i can’t think of a long question. maybe that
>   means i don’t have something selious to ask?

*Response:*

> Vary: Accept-Encoding BingAPIs-TraceId:
>   627B24C4E6D148E1B441F29A4872942B X-MSEdge-ClientID:
>   33F31CBFF80462EB27B316B9F935630A X-MSAPI-UserState: 983f
>   BingAPIs-Market: en-US X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A:
>   627B24C4E6D148E1B441F29A4872942B Ref B:
>   79AB388A3DFCBD481B71DB909B097DC3 Ref C: Tue Jan 10 13:46:16 2017 PST
>   apim-request-id: 645f3de5-6823-40d1-aea6-312e10d1eee2
>   Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;
>   preload Cache-Control: max-age=0, private Date: Tue, 10 Jan 2017
>   21:46:16 GMT P3P: CP="NON UNI COM NAV STA LOC CURa DEVa PSAa PSDa OUR
>   IND" Content-Length: 700 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   Expires: Tue, 10 Jan 2017 21:45:16 GMT
>
> {
>
> "_type": "SpellCheck",
>
> "flaggedTokens": [
>
> ```
> {
>
>   "offset": 15,
>
>   "token": "sentance",
>
>   "type": "UnknownToken",
>
>   "suggestions": [
>
>     {
>
>       "suggestion": "sentence",
>
>       "score": 0.687877624668787
>
>     }
>
>   ]
>
> },
>
> {
>
>   "offset": 86,
>
>   "token": "i",
>
>   "type": "UnknownToken",
>
>   "suggestions": [
>
>     {
>
>       "suggestion": "I",
>
>       "score": 0
>
>     }
>
>   ]
>
> },
>
> {
>
>   "offset": 137,
>
>   "token": "i",
>
>   "type": "UnknownToken",
>
>   "suggestions": [
>
>     {
>
>       "suggestion": "I",
>
>       "score": 0
>
>     }
>
>   ]
>
> },
>
> {
>
>   "offset": 52,
>
>   "token": "its",
>
>   "type": "UnknownToken",
>
>   "suggestions": [
>
>     {
>
>       "suggestion": "it's",
>
>       "score": 0.830337199488689
>
>     }
>
>   ]
>
> },
>
> {
>
>   "offset": 160,
>
>   "token": "selious",
>
>   "type": "UnknownToken",
>
>   "suggestions": [
>
>     {
>
>       "suggestion": "serious",
>
>       "score": 0.897224156828521
>
>     },
>
>     {
>
>       "suggestion": "delicious",
>
>       "score": 0.687622047694618
>
>     }
>
>   ]
>
> }
> ```
>
> ]
>
> }

Comment: Did you find the answer ? Because i've got the same error... Thanks

Comment: Yup, I've posted it below as the answer. Spell mode will correct queries of length upto 9 tokens only. I get longer strings, batched up in substrings of 9 tokens, to get around this

Comment: I get it ! Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a different source of Bing's API, but is probably the source of truth:
https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56e73033cf5ff80c2008c679/operations/56e73036cf5ff81048ee6727

> Spell - Meant to provide Search engine like spelling corrections. It
>   will correct small queries(up to length 9 tokens) without any casing
>   changes and will be more optimized (perf and relevance) towards search
>   like queries.